# relaunching the app fails android

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have an application in which i am generating a lot of notifications from a service.For each notification i have pending intent.Also pressing the home button stops my entire application and service using the following code

```
System.exit(0);
```

Firing the pending intent succeeds, but after pressing the home button if i am relaunching the app again it gives just a black screen and exits..Interesting thing is that if i click the app icon again it relaunch successfully..If the activity starts not using the pending intent, pressing the home button and relaunching everything works fine..

What should be the reason ? Any help will be greatly appreciated ..

Comment: You are stopping application yourself on home button press? If so, how did you managed this?

Comment: in "onPause()" i'm checking whether the app is in background or not..if so i will finish my app as well as service using the following..System.exit(0);

Comment: I guess it's a bad practice to stop application in this way. System may be left in corrupted state after this.

Comment: what to do then ? any solution.

Comment: Why do you use this? If you need to stop you services you can do it in gracefull way I think. Like Context.stopService().

Comment: how do we close our entire application ?

Comment: Why do you need this? In Android it's framework responsibility to manage application lyfecycle.

Comment: i dont want to run my app in background..it's a location based app..so will affect battery charge..

Comment: You can just shut down/pause you location related tasks in onPause(). It is common practice.

Comment: @boulder  do you know the reason for this scenario ?

Comment: Do you mind a chat? Call a time it's convenient to you to chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16626/relaunching-the-app-fails-android

Answer (score 0):

Is your service is not supposed to outlive your activity, you may not need the service at all. From your description, it looks like you can do everything directly from the activity.

Consider AsyncTask if you need some concurrency.

If the service is still the best option for you, then you should use Context.stopService() instead of System.exit() and clean up your background threads/notifications in the service's onDestroy().